# How to create custom checklist component flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created custom component with checkbox but can you help to handle callbacks

```
class MenuTile extends StatelessWidget {
      final bool isNew;
      final String name;
      final String price;
      final String calories;
      final List type;
      final bool isChecked;
      final bool isCheckedEnabled;
      final VoidCallback onPress;
      final VoidCallback onChecked;
      final IconData iconData;
    
      const MenuTile(
          {Key? key,
          required this.onPress,
          required this.name,
          required this.price,
          required this.iconData,
          required this.calories,
          required this.type,
          required this.isNew,
          required this.isChecked,
          required this.isCheckedEnabled,
          required this.onChecked})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19),
                splashColor: Colors.white60, // splash color
                onTap: () => onPress(),
                child: Row(children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19.0),
                        child: Material(
                            color: primaryColor, // button color
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 100,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new SizedBox(
                                    child: new Icon(
                                      Icons.payment,
                                      size: 58.0,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ), // icon
                                  // text
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        isNew
                            ? Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 60,
                                  height: 20,
                                  child: RoundButtonForTile(
                                    isSelect: buttonVegetarian,
                                    buttonDeSelectColor: vegColour,
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    buttonText: 'New',
                                    textColor: colorBlack,
                                    borderRadius: 1,
                                    buttonColor: vegColour,
                                    borderColor: vegColour,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            : Container(),
                        Text("Cafe Americano"),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [Text("CZK"), Text(price)],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        new Container(
                          height: 20,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ListView.builder(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                itemCount: type.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
                                    child: RoundWidget(
                                      showingText: type[index],
                                      onTap: () {},
                                      backGroundColor: vegColour,
                                      textColor: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Checkbox(
                        checkColor: Colors.white,
                        fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
                        value: isChecked,
                        onChanged: (bool? value) =>
                            onChecked(),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ])));
      }
    
    
      Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
        const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
          MaterialState.pressed,
          MaterialState.hovered,
          MaterialState.focused,
        };
        if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
          return Colors.teal;
        }
        return Colors.cyan;
      }
    }
```

how to onchange handle ?

```
  List<Map> details = [{"name": false, "ischecked": true,}];
MenuTile(
                                        name: 'Cafe Americano',
                                        calories: '10',
                                        onPress: () {
                                          print("sdd " + index.toString());
                                        },
                                        isNew: true,
                                        type: ['V'],
                                        price: '13',
                                        iconData: Icons.payment,
                                        isCheckedEnabled: true,
                                        isChecked: details[index]['ischecked'],
                                        onChecked: ()=>  {
                                        details[index]['ischecked'] = false,

                                          setState(() {

                                           }),
                                          print(details),

                                        });
                                  }),
                            )
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: check box not changing

Comment: Means your screen is not updating or not even getting the value?

Comment: @Diwyansh yes also how to send child ckeckbox value to parent